# Is my proof of G being a finite set of even order $\iff\exists g\in G$ with order 2 okay?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is my proof of G being a finite set of even order $\iff\exists g\in G$ with order 2 okay? (with $g\ne1$ obviously)

There are loads of duplicates of this question but none have "proved" it like I have, as such I'm panicky. I opted for a proof by contradiction.

I prove it as follows:

(1 denotes the identity, I'm using multiplicative notation)

An element of order 2 means $g^2=1$ which $\iff$ $g^{-1}=g$.

Let us assume that no such element exists, then $\forall g\in G, g\ne 1$ we have $g\ne g^{-1}$ (else it would be of order 2), however $(g^{-1})^{-1}=g$, so $|g|=|g^{-1}|$ ($|g|$ is the order of g)

Because $g\ne g^{-1}$ g and its inverse are distinct. Thus we can write our group as:

$1,g_1,g_1^{-1},\dots,g_n,g_n^{-1}$

We know there's an $n$ because the group is stated to be finite.

counting these distinct elements we see that there is the identity, and n pairs, meaning:

$|G|=2n+1$ - which is the very definition of an odd number.

So I have shown if a group has no element of order 2 than it must be odd, so it follows that to have an element of order 2 it must be of even order.

I am not saying all even groups have an element of order 2, I am saying that to have an element of order 2 it must be even.

However the simple tranposition that takes 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 is of order 2. Which is present in every symmetry group for n$\ge$2, and they all have even order ($|S_n|=n!$) but this feels a bit wooley.

Have I proved that all finite groups of even order have an element not equal to the identity that has order 2? I think so!

**side note**

I'm a bit uncomfortable with the n I pulled from the group being finite because I then showed the order to be 2n+1, is that "okay" because it seems a bit circular.

Comment: In fact All even groups have an element of order $2$..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik that's what I wanted to prove!

Comment: The proof looks fine to me.

Comment: But you have said "I am not saying all even groups have an element of order 2, I am saying that to have an element of order 2 it must be even." and you have not said anything to confirm after that?..

Comment: @IgorRivin so saying "If it doesn't have an element of order 2 it must be odd" means "all even ordered groups have an element of order 2" - that's the bit I'm unsure of

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik yeah, that's the bit I'm unsure of, can I go from that to the answer?

Comment: yes you can.. In fact you did.... you have proved that any group in which no element is of order $2$ is of odd order that is same as proving each group of even order contains an element of order $2$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik how? I have shown that to not have an element of order 2 means it is odd, thus to have an element of order 2 means it is even, but I have not shown all even groups have an element of order 2. (I don't think, I hate to sound silly :( )

Comment: Do you mean finite group, rather than finite set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown

$$\text{no element of order two}\implies\text{group has odd order}.$$

and conclude that "to have an element of even order the group must have even order." But you've actually shown something *stronger* than this: the **contrapositive** of the above implication is

$$\text{group has even order}\implies\text{there is an element of order two}.$$

Not only is it necessary for the group to have even order for there to be an element of order two; it is also *sufficient* for the group to have even order. (Note the contrapositive of any implication is logically equivalent to the original implication ... not so with converses.)

Also note that the order of an element is the *minimal* positive exponent needed to get it to make the identity element. This means the identity element itself has order $1$, not order $2$. Thus, an element has order two if and only if it satisfies both $g^2=e$ and $g\ne e$. So if you state "$g$ has order two," it is automatic that $g\ne e$; you don't have to tack that condition on separately because it is built-in.

Comment: I've not come across contrapositives before, but (and I fear seeming silly saying this) what if there's an element of say order 4? All (I think) I have shown is that no order 2 $\implies$ group has odd order. Thus __if__ there is an order 2, it is not odd ($\iff$ it is even), I have not shown that there __is__ an element of order 2 if it is even. (I don't think...)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive - nifty, I can (abuse|use) the two states, odd and even, or has an element of order 2 and doesn't have an element of order 2. I'd be nice to make sense of it in word form, thanks Anon!

Comment: @AlecTeal It doesn't matter if there is an element of order $4$. You've shown it's not possible for a group to have even order *and* no element of order two ($\Rightarrow$ group has odd order) at the same time. Therefore, if a group has even order, it must have an element of order two. This is the gist of contraposition. But knowing basic logic is important: $\rm A\Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\rm\neg B\Rightarrow\neg A$. Here, $\rm A$="no element of order two" and $\rm B$="group has odd order." Then $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ are ... ?